# Docker does not have a release file?

Tags: apt, package-management, docker, ppa

When I run `sudo apt update` I get this error

```
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am a complete Linux noob, so it would be appreciated for the answers be simplified.

There are a few things I have tried to fix the problem with, using ppa purge doesn't work because when I run it,

```
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

for the most part, I get the same error. Even when I get this to work with a different type of command, as said before I am a Linux noob, and I cannot find the name of the ppa. So I run my command like this

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:docker
```

As said before I need help understanding my answers, and I still need more help learning what the post means.

SYSTEM:

OS: PoP!OS, Based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Here is a steam benchmark for more advanced info about [my PC](https://pastebin.com/WwguS1jF)

Comment: Your entry in `sources.list` (or somewhere in `sources.list.d/`) is wrong. There should not be a backslash in there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error message:

```
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release' does not have a Release file.
```

1. Run `echo $(lsb_release -cs)` to print your distribution's codename.
2. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or somewhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) for editing in nano text editor with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` or `sudo nano /path/to/somewhere-in-/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`) and change this line:

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ stable
   ```

   by replacing the backslash character `\`  with your distribution's codename.
3. Run `sudo apt update` to refresh your package database.

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Comment: This didn't help me, when I open the file, I dont see the line, I see this instead:
 ## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy

# Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs

# CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.

# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 22.04 _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20221116)]/ jammy >

Comment: @TravisGames If you have clarifications to your questions (like the contents of the `apt` sources list), then please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon (Ubuntu 22.04.01)

1. `cat /etc/os-release`

   ```
   NAME="Linux Mint"
   VERSION="21.3 (Virginia)"
   ID=linuxmint
   ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
   PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 21.3"
   VERSION_ID="21.3"
   HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
   SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.linuxmint.com/"
   BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
   PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
   VERSION_CODENAME=virginia
   UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
   ```

Using `UBUNTU_CODENAME`'s value, I did the next step.

2. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   virginia stable
   ```

   Change `virginia` to `UBUNTU_CODENAME`'s value.
   `virginia` -> `jammy`

For some reason the command suggested in the official install put a wrong value in that place. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

3. End result looks like this, inside the file we just modified:

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   jammy stable
   ```
4. `sudo apt-get update`

Good luck